# How can I loop the Try block until no exceptions are caught?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

How can I loop through the Try block part of a Try-Catch until no exceptions are caught?

For example; you input the denominator as 0 (divide by 0), an ArithmeticException is caught, handled, and the Try block is run again (Asks you to enter numerator and denominator again). When nothing gets caught, the program stops.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Activity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fraction sampleFraction = new Fraction(8,3);
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            try {
                System.out.print ("Enter the numerator:  ");
                sampleFraction.setNumerator(scan.nextInt());        
                System.out.print ("Enter the denominator:  ");
                sampleFraction.setDenominator(scan.nextInt());  
                
                System.out.println ("The fraction " + sampleFraction.getNumerator() + "/" +
                        sampleFraction.getDenominator() + " is equal to " + sampleFraction.toMixedNumber());
            }
            catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.out.println("You can't divide by zero! \n");
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter whole numbers (Integers) only! \n");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("An unexpected exception was caught; please try again! \n");
            }
                
                scan.close();
        }
        
    }
```

This is just the driver/main class. I can provide the Fraction class if needed, though that just handles all of the methods that calculate and print the math.

Comment: just keep a boolean that you only set to false at the end of the try block -> while (myBoolean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the try/catch with a loop, and break at the end of the try block:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    // Do things that might throw exceptions...

    // This breaks out of the `while` loop.
    break;
  } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    // ...
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    // ...
  } /* etc */

  // Unless we break/return in the catch blocks, the loop will execute again.
}
```

---

*With that said*, it's better to avoid the exceptions in the first place. Exceptions are for handling *exceptional* things; if you know what causes an exception to be thrown, you may be able to avoid it.

For example, `ArithmeticException` occurs when you try to divide by zero: instead of relying on catching the exception, check that the denominator isn't zero first:

```
int denominator = scan.nextInt();
if (denominator == 0) {
  System.out.println("You can't divide by zero! \n");
  continue;
}
sampleFraction.setDenominator(denominator);
```

Comment: Okay so I did that. When it catches the ArithmeticException, it works perfectly. Prints the message about division by 0 and then loops back to the Try block. When it catches an InputMismatchException though, it loops both the print statement in the catch block, as well as the "Enter the numerator" print statement infinitely together.

Also; this is for a class assignment which instructs to handle any given exception that might occur, or I would just check that the denominator isn't zero.

Comment: You need to consume the thing which isn't of the right type, for example you've entered a string or a double, not an int. Put `scan.nextLine()` in the catch block. Also, you can use `scan.hasNextInt()` to check if `scan.nextInt()` will succeed, to avoid that exception.

Comment: "this is for a class assignment which instructs to handle any given exception that might occur" if you stop the exception from occurring, it can't occur. Also, you're handling exceptions that _cannot_ occur, by handling `Exception` (as opposed to, say, `RuntimeException`). Catching all exceptions is really not a good practice.